# Adding a cap to a logistic regression

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I'm running a log regression to model out reach curves. A typical reach curve looks like:
[image: reach curve]

So using a log regression seems the obvious choice. The reach curves are based on historical  activity, but I have some additional knowledge of the total user count, so I know for certain that the reach can never exceed a certain number.

I am having a hard time blending a modelled log curve with a known hard cap.  Ideally I think I should add some modifier that increases the diminishing effect as the output approaches the known cap, to help preserve the curve on the lower values (where most the activity happens) while adding in the known cap to prevent the model from returning values where the reach is 125% of all users.

Currently i'm using scipy optimize, i've added a ton of synthetic data at the known max to try and force this model to respect the max, but I think i'm going down the wrong road here:

[image: current model]

I feel like I need another function that takes the output of this one, and adds a penalty increasing in strength as the value approaches the known max, but I can't seem to get it to work, my curve keeps going negative or the blend comes out really jarring like a hard cap, any thoughts on how to approach this?

Comment: What are you DOING with this data?  Is the hard cap really meaningful for the model?  Couldn't you reach that many users if they were available?  I'm not sure you're doing your limiting at the right spot.

Comment: The log() function increases more slowly with its argument, but, nevertheless it increases indefinitely. Why don’t you try fitting one of the “switch”-type functions that have a natural upper asymptote. An obvious one would be tanh(), the hyperbolic tangent. Try fitting y=A.tanh(Bx). Another one might be y=A(1-exp(-Bx)) (for positive x)

Comment: @TimRoberts the data is to model expected reach for a known number of impressions bought.  I put in how much I spend, it tells me on average how many people I reach based on histortical data.  There is known data on how many people are available total.  Such that currently the model can return 125% of total users, which is what i'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @lastchance I assume we can only use the postive curve from tanh to avoid the sigmoid s shape? The S shape is why i've avoided sigmoid so far.  e.g.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0JA0.png

Comment: There are many switch curves that can work. If you changed your “sigmoid” curve S(x) to 2S(x)-1 it would probably look very much like  tanh(x).

Comment: What your curves do in x<0 is irrelevant. I wouldn’t worry about an “S shape”.

Comment: @lastchance this worked, much thanks to you and your gigantic brain :)

Answer (score 2):

Per the comment from @lastchance fitting to tanh produced the necessary curve for this:

[image]

For reference the functions used with scipy optimise here are:

```
#tanh function
def tanh_func(x, A, B):
    return A * np.tanh(B * x)

#log-log function
def comp_loglog_func(x, A, B):
    return A * (1 - np.exp(-B * x))
```